# Compare file sizes in Makefile

Tags: file, makefile, compare, pipe, bc

I would like to compare the sizes of two files within the scope of a rule in my Makefile.
In my rule, I'm converting PDFs to PNGs like this:

```
.pdf.png:
    @convert $< -resize 800x800 -quality 85% $@
```

Since some of the PNGs are not significantly smaller than their PDF parent but have pretty bad quality, I would like to delete those PNGs after the conversion process.
My first idea was to add something like this to the above rule:

```
COMP = "`wc -c <$<` / `wc -c <$@`"|bc
if [ $COMP -lt 2 ]; then \
    rm $@; \
fi
```

The first line gives me the compression factor of the old PDF file vs the new PNG file. That is, "bad compression" giving a value of 0 or 1 should result in deleting the freshly generated PNG file.
Unfortunately, I'm not really experienced in writing Makefiles and, specifically, in piping commands.
So, my problem is, I don't know how to use the result of the first line of the second code snippet and use it in the if statement to compare it with another value.
Any hints would be highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of a recipe is executed in a different shell. So, you can use shell variables only in a single line of your recipe. But you can also use line-continuation (`\`) for better readability:

```
var=`some-shell-command`; \
echo "$$var"
```

is equivalent to:

```
var=`some-shell-command`; echo "$$var"
```

Remember to escape the make expansion (`$$`) when needed. In your case, a recipe could be:

```
%.png: %.png
    @convert $< -resize 800x800 -quality 85% $@; \
    i=`stat -c%s $<`; \
    o=`stat -c%s $@`; \
    $$(( o > 2*i )) && rm -f $@ || true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Renaud. What is the `|| true` for in your example?
Also, I would like to stick with the aproach from above to compare the fraction of `size(input_file) / size(output_file)` with an integer.
By comparing only the two sizes with each other I will always have a difference. However, I want to remove the output file only iff the difference in size is significant, i.e. the fraction is 1 or 0 (output file is even bigger).
How can I combine these two results of `stat` in one fraction?

Comment: If the arithmetic comparison fails the `|| true` part is evaluated. Without this the complete expression would exit with a non-zero status, make would consider that the recipe failed and would stop with an error message. And yes, of course, you can remove the output file if it is more than twice bigger than the input file. I would personally prefer `$$(( o > 2 * i ))` instead of a division because of rounding of integer divisions. But your way works too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got it now. I adopted the approach of Renaud Pacalet to my needs. For those who are interested, my rule looks like follows:

```
.pdf.png:
    @convert $< -resize 800x800 -quality 85% $@
    @echo converted $<
    @COMP=$$((`stat -c%s "$<"`/`stat -c%s "$@"`)); [ $$COMP -lt 2 ] && echo "bad compression: remove $@" && rm $@ || true
```

This resizes the input image and, if the integer ratio of `input/output < 2`, removes the output file again (at a ratio of 0 or 1 I assume the compression was bad).